# How dangerous are HASEL artificial muscles with its Kv requirements?

Tags: current, electric

So, I don't know much about electricity and this kind of stuff, so I hope I don't make too many misconceptions.

What are [HASEL artificial muscles](https://youtu.be/xtXxnGg0xO0)? It is a “Hydraulically amplified self-healing electrostatics (HASEL) actuator”, in a simple way: it is two electromagnetic materials sandwiching a liquid material (normally oil), once an electric current pass through the plates, they attract each other, forcing the entire package to decrease its volume, simulating a muscular contraction.

So, the problem is that they require around 10-20 Kv to be able to contract, at first I thought that this muscle may be dangerous to just play around with. But there is the saying that "What kills you isn't the voltage, but the current", so maybe I'm picturing everything incorrectly.

The problem is: I couldn't find anything besides the Kv information, no amps or watts (not even in their official online store). [Here is the link to the article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/adma.202003375).

I probably missed something in the article or simply misread it, but still, whatever current requirement this Artificial Muscle is, it is high enough to be dangerous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, always take precautions when dealing with electricity. Discharging capacitors, removing metal jewelry, safety glasses, insulated tools, etc. If it's a commercially available product then I would expect it to come with specific instructions for what's appropriate for the device, and you should comply with all written safety procedures.

That said, yes [static electric shocks are about 10kV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity), but you are correct that it doesn't do permanent damage because the current is low.

**That** said, mechanical actuators capable of appreciable motion could probably draw enough instantaneous power to be very dangerous. I wouldn't put my hand near an exposed automotive 12V window regulator winch system and I likewise wouldn't want to put my hand near an exposed high voltage actuator either.

If you look at it and think, wow, this could mangle my hand, don't touch it.